# Complex projections for Grails criteria

Tags: hibernate, grails, hibernate-criteria

I'm searching the way of expressing the following SQL in a Grails (or just Hibernate) criteria form.

```
select 
    sum(if( r.type = 'a', r.amount, 0)) as sum_a,    
    sum(if( r.type = 'b', r.amount, 0)) as sum_b    
from records r;
```

Here I want to get two sums for different subsets of rows defined by specific column. The goal is to get them in a single request.

Well, looking at a Projections class I see that it provides only a basic sum aggregate for a property so anticipated answer is no, but what could be the best solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the sqlProjection, it allow you to write some native projection .

Maybe it ll look like this :

```
Projections.sqlProjection("sum(if( {alias}.type = 'a', {alias}.amount, 0)) as sum_a",   new String[] { "sum_a" }, new Type[] { StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER})
```

Comment: in groovy language you cannot create arrays using java syntax (new String[]{"one","two"}) because groovy reserve curly braces for closures, you may use instead this syntax: ["one","two"].toArray()

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CASE...WHEN](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#d5e3266) hibernate statement inside `sqlGroupProjection` expression like this:

```
Records.createCriteria().list{
    projections {
      sqlGroupProjection '(case type when \'a\' then sum(amount) else 0 end) as sum_a, (case type when \'b\' then sum(amount) else 0 end) as sum_b', 'type', ['sum_a', 'sum_b'], [INTEGER, INTEGER]
    }
}
```

This generates the following SQL:

```
select (case type when 'a' then sum(amount) else 0 end) as sum_a, (case type when 'b' then sum(amount) else 0 end) as sum_b from records this_ group by type
```

It works for me, hope this helps.